# How to pass custom data to deserialization function

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization

I'm doing some C# IO work and I want to import/export data from a few classes.
After looking for a while, it seems serialization is pretty close to what I want.

However, there is a problem. I have a XML file that describes members of a certain class(which I will refer as `ValueWithId`), which are aggregated in a class which I will call `CollectionOfValuesWithId` for the purposes of this question.

`ValueWithId` is a class that contains a `string` member called `ShortName`, which is unique. There is only one `ShortName` per `ValueWithId` and all `ValueWithId` have a non-null `ShortName`. `CollectionOfValuesWithId` contains a function to find the `ValueWithId` with a given `ShortName`.

When serializing, I do *NOT* want to store `ValueWithId` nor `CollectionOfValuesWithId` in the output file. Instead, I just want to store the `ShortName` in the file.
So far, so good. I just need to use `SerializationInfo.AddValue("ValueWithId", MyValueWIthId.ShortName)`.

The problem comes with deserialization. Some googling suggests that to read data from a file one would do this:

```
public SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    string name = (string)info.GetValue("ValueWithId", typeof(string));
}
```

However, the string is not enough to recover the `ValueWithId` instance. I also need the `CollectionOfValuesWithId`. I want something like this:

```
public SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId(SerializationInfo info,
   StreamingContext ctxt, CollectionOfValuesWithId extraParameter)
```

In other words, I need to pass extra data to the deserialization constructor. Does anyone know any way to do this or any alternatives?

Comment: Can you show your class and expected xml?

Comment: @L.B I'm using XML for the `ValueWithId`, but the serialization itself will be from/to binary, not XML. I really don't care about the generated file, I just don't want the `ValueWithId`s to end up there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The important class to do this is `StreamingContext`.
This class conveniently has a property named [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.streamingcontext.context%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(which can be set in the constructor parameter `additional`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h58hxyt6.aspx):

> additional
>       Type: System.Object
>       Any additional information to be associated with the
>   StreamingContext. This information is available to any object that
>   implements ISerializable or any serialization surrogate. Most users do
>   not need to set this parameter.

So here is some sample code regarding how to do this(tested on Mono, but I think it should work on Windows):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class ValueWithId
{
    public string ShortName;
    public string ActualValue;

    public ValueWithId(string shortName, string actualValue)
    {
        ShortName = shortName;
        ActualValue = actualValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ShortName + "->" + ActualValue;
    }
}

public class CollectionOfValuesWithId
{
    private IList<ValueWithId> Values = new List<ValueWithId>();

    public void AddValue(ValueWithId val)
    {
        Values.Add(val);
    }

    public ValueWithId GetValueFromId(string id)
    {
        foreach (var value in Values)
            if (value.ShortName == id)
                return value;
        return null;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId : ISerializable
{
    public ValueWithId Val;

    public SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId(ValueWithId val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }

    public SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        string valId = (string)info.GetString("Val");
        CollectionOfValuesWithId col = ctxt.Context as CollectionOfValuesWithId;
        if (col != null)
            Val = col.GetValueFromId(valId);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
    {
        //Store Val.ShortName instead of Val because we don't want to store the entire object
        info.AddValue("Val", Val.ShortName);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Content="+Val;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CollectionOfValuesWithId col = new CollectionOfValuesWithId();
        col.AddValue(new ValueWithId("foo", "bar"));

        SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId sc = new SomeClassThatUsesValueWithId(col.GetValueFromId("foo"));

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.File, col));

        using (var stream = new FileStream("foo", FileMode.Create))
        {
            bf.Serialize(stream, sc);
        }

        col.GetValueFromId("foo").ActualValue = "new value";

        using (var stream2 = new FileStream("foo", FileMode.Open))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bf.Deserialize(stream2));
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Content=foo->new value
```

Which is exactly what I wanted.